# Is it true or false that if $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, then $A$ and $B$ are independent events.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

I'm helping my brother with probability theory. He just covered the definition of two events being independent, but when I saw the definition in his textbook, I was a bit confused.

I'm familiar with the following notion of independency:

> If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

What I had a hard time finding out is whether the converse is true, i.e. if $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, then $A$ and $B$ are independent events. I swear I remember my professor in undergrad telling me it is not in general true. But my brother's textbook states it as a definition.

Comment: It is a definition, so yes, the converse is true.

Comment: There’s a similar formula where independent variables are uncorrelated but not all uncorrelated variables are independent.

Comment: @Eric Oh okay, that's probably what I was thinking of. Thanks

Comment: In Mathematics all definitions are if and only if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true.

For any two events, we know by [this axiom of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#As_an_axiom_of_probability) that
$$P(A \cap B) = P(A|B) \cdot P(B)$$

Given that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$, (assuming $P(B) ≠ 0$), we get

$$P(A|B) = P(A)$$

This implies that the probability of A under the condition that B has already occurred is the same as probability of A occurring without having to know if B occurred.

In other words, A and B are independent events.